# Selenium WebDriver and TestNG: IE Thread Consumption Issue

Tags: multithreading, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

**Situation:**
I have a TestNG suite that runs seven WebDriver tests using four threads.

**Problem:**
The IE WebDriver takes much longer to execute these tests than the Firefox and Chrome drivers.

**One of the causes:** 
IE does not take advantage of available threads until NO threads are being used.

**Specifics:**
In Firefox and Chrome, four browser instances launch when the tests begin. When the first of those four tests finishes, one of the remaining three tests immediately launches because there is an open thread. IE also launches four browser instances when the tests begin. However, when the first test completes in IE (meaning that only three browser instances are running), a fourth one does not open until the ones that are still running have all finished.

**Goal:**
My goal is to make IE consume available threads as soon as they become available (like Firefox and Chrome).

**Code:**

Opening suite tag from testng.xml:

```
<suite thread-count="4" verbose="0" name="Command line suite" parallel="tests">
```

If you need additional code to make sense of things, please let me know.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: According to the official wiki, it is *kind of* supported, but untested and thus you'll run into issues: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Multiple_instances_of

Comment: I would guess that the IEDriver is actually probably re-using 1 system thread to run the multiple IE browsers, unlike Firefox.

Comment: @djangofan I don't see how IEDriver could be re-using 1 system thread when it runs 4 browser instances to start with and then 4 again after the first 4 have finished.